# How can I calculate standard deviation for every block in an image

Tags: image-processing, std, matlab

I'm trying to use [this example from the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) to calculate standard deviation for every 8x8 pixel block in the image but I can't use it well in this case , so can anybody help me  to compute std for each block.

```
 fun = @(block_struct) std2(block_struct.data) * ones(size(block_struct.data))
 I2 = blockproc('moon.tif',[8 8],fun);
 figure;
 imshow('moon.tif');
 figure;
 imshow(I2 , []);
```

Comment: Hi, in future you can just edit your previous question instead of re-asking it. This one has more detail so I'm going to vote to close your previous one.

Comment: Also what exactly is wrong with your code?What is wrong with the result you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want `nlfilter` (or `colfilt` with `'sliding'` option).  With `blockproc`, it is splitting the image into distinct blocks *that don't overlap* and writing out in blocks by replicating the standard deviation value it calculates.  With `nlfilter` it is a sliding window so you get a smooth output image.

The syntax of `nlfilter` is different, so it would be applied like this:

```
Iout = nlfilter(imread('moon.tif'),[8 8],@std2);
```

Alternatively, you can use `colfilt` to get better performance:

```
Iout = colfilt(double(imread('moon.tif')),[8 8],'sliding',@std);
```

Comment: this is good work but still i can't replace @std2 by the real function  i'am sorry i don't know how

Comment: No difference in this case, but you can with `blockfilt` as above.